# RelativeLayout on top of other RelativeLayout in same Activity

Tags: android

I have an activity with root item being a RelativeLayout. At one point I want to display another view of top of this, but don't want to use another Activity since this would remove/reset the previous contents (I want to keep it as is). I just want to push the view on top, and in the added view there is a button to close it again.

Comment: Use Dialog with custom layout for that, the best way in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define all your layouts in xml file. setting each and every layout..

Set Visibility of your view 'gone' when you want to hide that and set Visibility 'Visible' when you want to show that on top...

Answer (score 0):

You can use alert dialog, in this case your background activity will remain as it is and you can customize dialog as well.

```
  public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
Button okButton;
/*
 * param context
 * 
 */
public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    /** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the title */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    /** When OK Button is clicked, dismiss the dialog */
    if (v == okButton)
        dismiss();
}
```

You will give it your custom layout with relative layout or whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

I went with actually creating another Activity. Maybe it's not what I wanted (the first Activity's content will not be visible with the new one) but at least its state seems to be preserved when Back button is pushed in the new Activity.